# Regex to remove everything BEFORE and AFTER letter or numbers on a string

Tags: php, regex, string, character

I'm making a function using PHP to clean a name string.

So, I have names like these:

```php
$name_1 = ' \'Brian    O\'Ril"*ley';
$name_2 = ' \'   " José Sant\'Anna';

# Output expected:
# Brian O'Rilley
# José Sant'Anna
```

My function code:

```php
function cleanName($string)
{
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Remove everything before first letter and after last letter
  # --------------------------------------------------
  $string = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+/','',$string);
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Clean spaces
  # --------------------------------------------------
  $string = htmlentities($string,null,'utf-8');
  $string = str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',$string);
  $string = preg_replace('!\s+!',' ',$string);
  $string = html_entity_decode($string);
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Replace quotes
  # --------------------------------------------------
  $string = str_replace(array('`','´','´´','``','"'),'\'',$string);
  $string = preg_replace("/'{2,}/","'",$string);
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Remove everything but letters, single spaces, simple quotes, and ISO-8859-1 characters
  # --------------------------------------------------
  $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 \'\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]+/u','',$string);
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Upper case on fisrt letters
  # --------------------------------------------------
  $string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Output
  # --------------------------------------------------
  return $string;
}
```

The code does pretty much everything I need, BUT:

```php
# This one only removes BEFORE - I also need to remove AFTER
$string = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+/','',$string);
```

I'm really struggling to find a way to remove anything after the last letter/number.

Can someone help me with that?
If the before and after it's on a single regex, even better.
Any other suggestion to make my code better is welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string = 'abc87#@-';
echo preg_replace('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*).*$/', '$1', $string);
```

Prints:

```
abc87
```

The idea is that in scanning the string `abc87#@-`, `abc87` becomes capture group 1 and `#@-` is everything else (i.e. `.*`). Thus the regex matches the entire string and you therefore replacing the entire string with just capture group 1.